# Почему getch () при нажатии ^D возвращает 4, а не -1?

Tags: linux, c, ncurses

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    initscr ();

    noecho ();

    i = getch ();
    printw ("%i\n", i);

    getch ();

    endwin ();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Возвращает при нажатии `ctr+d` 4, хотя обычно возвращает `EOF`, которое равно -1

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell

Comment: блин, я английский не знаю

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если в двух словах, то обычно терминал работает в *каноническом* режиме и (помимо прочего), когда в такой терминал прилетает ASCII символ End Of Transmission, то драйвер терминал преобразует его в EOF для активного процесса.

`curses` (помимо прочего) снимает флаг `ICANON` (см. `man 3 tcsetattr`), переводя тем самым терминал в обычный режим. И соответственно процесс получает весь ввод (включая управляющие ASCII символы) как-есть.